# method "where" does not work when switched from will_paginate to pagy gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, will-paginate

My will_paginate code in controller:

```rb
@posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 100).order('created_at DESC')
```

My pagy code that replaced it:

```rb
@pagy, @posts = pagy_countless(Post.order('created_at DESC'), items:5, link_extra: 'class="" style="color:#222222; margin:3px;"')
```

My view where the problem is:

```
<% @posts.where(user_id: current_user.friends).each do |post| %>
```

The error message:

```
undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x00007f94329d1f70>
Did you mean?  when
```

What am I doing wrong? The previous will_paginate implementation worked in terms of showing all the posts of user's friends. I'm lost as to what changed in switching to pagy.

UPDATE:

So for the moment, I've solved this by moving the "where..." logic to controller. So:

```rb
@pagy, @posts = pagy_countless(Post.where(user_id: current_user.friends).order('created_at DESC'), items:5, link_extra: 'class="" style="color:#222222; margin:3px;"')
```

And now it works as before. But I'm still confused as to why I had to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware `pagy_countless` returns an array of items, instead of an ActiveRecord collection. That's why you can't use ActiveRecord methods on `@posts` (like `where`).

Follow my link to see that collection is transformed into array using `to_a` and then it is returned as second argument of `pagy_countless`: https://github.com/ddnexus/pagy/blob/bd88866ad6001ae1ef6ce63080d36ecff7bc5603/lib/pagy/extras/countless.rb#L29

Two comments:
1. You must use ActiveRecord filters before calling `pagy_countless` on your collection (eg: `where` clauses)
2. If you need to filter records after pagination (which does not make sense in most of the cases), you must use `Array` methods like `select` of `reject` as following `@posts.select { |record| record.user.in?(current_user.friends) }`